# How to convert this chm file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, ebooks, calibre, chm

I want to convert [a chm file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nhvxs0yegkoddn/Voice__Data_Communications_Handbook%20by%20Bates.chm) to a pdf file.
Calibre's command ebook-convert `ebook-convert 1.chm 1.pdf` only converts the first 7 pages of the chm file into a pdf file, while the chm file has much more pages. How can I convert the whole chm file into a pdf file? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use chm2pdf from the universe repository.

To install chm2pdf in Ubuntu 14.04-18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install chm2pdf
```

You then run the command like this:

```
chm2pdf OPTIONS FILENAME.CHM FILENAME.PDF
```

Note that as `OPTIONS`, you must at least specify either

- `--book` (structured output: headings, chapters, ...),
- `--webpage` (unstructured, but page breaks between different documents/URLs in the CHM file), or
- `--continuous` (unstructured output)

For more information, see `man chm2pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

Try a different online converter.  Zamzar is useful if the CHM file is under 100MB.

```
http://www.zamzar.com/convert/chm-to-pdf/
```

Another option is to use chm2pdf.  To do so, use the following commands in a terminal session...

```
sudo apt-get install chm2pdf
chm2pdf foo.chm foo.pdf
```

That second command assumes that your CHM file is named 'foo.chm', so adjust that as appropriate.

Source: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-convert-chm-files-into-pdf-files-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: +1 chm2pdf looks good, but no need for none Ubuntu based solutions (website) on ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: Just giving Tim more options (in case chm2pdf is not available in his repositories, in the interests of giving a complete answer. :)

Comment: Besides, if it's a small CHM, and this is the only one that needs conversion, it might not be worth the effort of installing additional software.  ^.^