# No more chm2pdf?

Tags: software-installation

Trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706012/how-to-convert-this-chm-file-to-pdf) discussion I tried to install `chm2pdf` but apparently it no longer exists. Please advise.

Comment: It's available on 18.0.4.